# How to purify myself

Tags: taharah

If impurity like urine or madhi touch my lip or face. How to wash it?
If I wash my face like wudu water will enter my nose and drop in clothes. Do this make my clothes and nose impure?

Comment: How will urine or madhi reach your lips? Washing actually means that you remove the najasah.

Comment: baby touch with his dirty hand

Answer (score 0):

I have found your answer in youtube, [here it is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_nSZpqhd78).
The answer is: **NO**, your nose and clothes will **not** be **impure** because when you wash your face with water, the water overwhelms the impurity and water itself will not be impure. The reason for this is water overwhelms impurity. In that video I have given the link above, there Shykh Assim al-Hakeem explains nicely about why the rules is like this and you will understands the matter completely. Jajakallahu khairan.